# Prevent dropdown menu to push div underneath

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular

I'm working on an Angular project for an e-commerce platform and I'm having some problems with a dropdown menu. The menu pushes the div underneath down, but I want to go over it, not pushing it.
Here's some images: 
[image]

After clicking the menu:
[image]

While I'm trying to achieve this (this is the template html page):
[image]

As you can see the menu goes over the div underneath and doesn't push it down.
Here it is the code:

```js
$('.hero__categories__all').on('click', function(){
      $('.hero__categories ul').slideToggle(400);
  });
```

```css
.hero.hero-normal {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.hero.hero-normal .hero__categories {
  position: relative;
}

.hero.hero-normal .hero__categories ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 46px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.hero__categories__all {
 background: #7fad39;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
 padding: 10px 25px 10px 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.hero__categories__all i {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #ffffff;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.hero__categories__all span {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.hero__categories__all:after {
 position: absolute;
 right: 18px;
 top: 9px;
 content: "3";
 font-family: "ElegantIcons";
 font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.hero__categories ul {
 border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
 padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.hero__categories ul li {
 list-style: none;
}

.hero__categories ul li a {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #1c1c1c;
 line-height: 39px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero__categories">
                  <div class="hero__categories__all">
                      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                      <span>Categorie</span>
                  </div>
                  <ul>
                      <li *ngFor="let category of categories">
                        <a href="/products/{{category.name.replace(' ', '_') | lowercase}}">
                          {{category.name}}
                        </a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
</div>
```

I'm not really a CSS and HTML expert so thanks for your help!

**EDIT 1**

I gave position: absolute to the ul in css code and now this happens:
[image]

Comment: Your provided code works .Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/u25psyzc/1/)

Comment: What do you mean? As you can see in the images I provided the dropdown menu pushes the other view down. The code I provided is actually into a component, every other component that is under is being pushed down. I tried to insert another div under the menu and the problem is the same. I really don't know why your code works and mine doesn't

Comment: can you provide demo code ?so that i can test it .. because current code doesn't have such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, all I had to do was adding position: absolute in css to the ul element and top and left properties in place of padding-top and padding-left. I also removed padding-bottom